# SQLAlchemy printing raw SQL from create()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons

I am giving Pylons a try with SQLAlchemy, and I love it, there is just one thing, is it possible to print out the raw SQL `CREATE TABLE` data generated from `Table().create()` before it's executed?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

```py
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable
    
print(CreateTable(table))
```

If you are using declarative syntax:

```py
print(CreateTable(Model.__table__))
```

**Update:**

Since I have the accepted answer and there is important information in [klenwell answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10216304/242786), I'll also add it here.

You can get the SQL for your specific database (MySQL, Postgresql, etc.) by compiling with your engine.

```
print(CreateTable(Model.__table__).compile(engine))
```

**Update 2:**

@jackotonye Added in the comments a way to do it without an engine.

```py
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

print(CreateTable(Model.__table__).compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect()))
```

Comment: This works for the models, but with many-to-many relationships, how do I print out the associative tables, since they are also needed in order for the entire system to work?

Comment: You have to declare them as well. Look at the doc http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#self-referential-many-to-many-relationship. In the example of the doc, `node_to_node` would be `table` of my first example.

Comment: Great, this works for me! Howerver, I still can't see indices defined at declarative syntax `__table_args__` member. Any ideas?

Comment: This can also be done without an engine                                                   `print(CreateTable(Model.__table__).compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect()))`

Comment: Exemple with mysqlconnector :
```from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import mysqlconnector
print(CreateTable(AttribResults.__table__).compile(dialect=mysqlconnector.dialect()))
```

Comment: Where is the `Model` coming from? Is it sqlalchemy? I can't figure out where to import it from

Comment: @Guus, it's one of the class that you write that inherits from a `declarative_base`. E.g. `class User(Base):` (`User` is `Model` in that example).

Answer (score 21):

You can set up you engine to dump the metadata creation sequence, using the following:

```
def metadata_dump(sql, *multiparams, **params):
    # print or write to log or file etc
    print(sql.compile(dialect=engine.dialect))

engine = create_engine(myDatabaseURL, strategy='mock', executor=metadata_dump)
metadata.create_all(engine)
```

One advantage of this approach is that enums and indexes are included in the printout. Using `CreateTable` leaves this out.

Another advantage is that the order of the schema definitions is correct and (almost) usable as a script.

Comment: If you're using an RDBMS that requires semicolons, replace the body of the function with this `print(str(sql.compile(dialect=engine.dialect)) + ";")` to get the semicolons in the output.

Comment: With the new Version (1.4), it looks a bit different:
`engine = create_mock_engine("postgresql://", metadata_dump)` and
`metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=False)`

Comment: Interesting approach.  So you are pulling out the query from the engine object.

Answer (score 15):

I needed to get the raw table sql in order to setup tests for some existing models. Here's a successful unit test that I created for SQLAlchemy 0.7.4 based on [Antoine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3150687/1093087) as proof of concept:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable
from model import Foo

sql_url = "sqlite:///:memory:"    
db_engine = create_engine(sql_url)

table_sql = CreateTable(Foo.table).compile(db_engine)
self.assertTrue("CREATE TABLE foos" in str(table_sql))
```

Answer (score 7):

It turns out this is straight-forward:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, String, MetaData

metadata = MetaData()

users = Table('users', metadata,
              Column('username', String)
)

statement = CreateTable(users)

print(statement.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect()))
```

Outputs this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    username VARCHAR
)
```

Going further, it can even support bound parameters in prepared statements.

### Reference

> How do I render SQL expressions as strings, possibly with bound parameters inlined?
>
> ...
>
> or without an Engine:
>
> ```
> from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
> print(statement.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect()))
> ```

SOURCE: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/sqlexpressions.html#faq-sql-expression-string

### Example: Using SQL Alchemy to generate a user rename script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
from sqlalchemy import bindparam, Table, Column, String, MetaData

metadata = MetaData()

users = Table('users', metadata,
              Column('username', String)
)

renames = []

with open('users.csv') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile):
        renames.append({
            'from': row['sAMAccountName'],
            'to': row['mail']
        })

for rename in renames:
    stmt = (users.update()
            .where(users.c.username == rename['from'])
            .values(username=rename['to']))
    print(str(stmt.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect(),
                           compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})) + ';')
```

When processing this users.csv:

```
sAMAccountName,mail
bmcboatface,boaty.mcboatface@example.com
ndhyani,naina.dhyani@contoso.com
```

Gives output like this:

```
UPDATE users SET username='boaty.mcboatface@example.com' WHERE users.username = 'bmcboatface';
UPDATE users SET username='naina.dhyani@contoso.com' WHERE users.username = 'ndhyani';users.username = 'ndhyani';
```

Why a research vessel has an email address is yet to be determined. I have been in touch with Example Inc's IT team and have had no response.

Comment: Best answer, organized and runnable. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure, @Devy. Thank you for independently confirming it works :)

Answer (score 4):

May be you mean `echo` parameter of sqlalchemy.create_engine?

/tmp$ cat test_s.py

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Department(Base):
    __tablename__ = "departments"

    department_id = sa.Column(sa.types.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.types.Unicode(100), unique=True)
    chief_id = sa.Column(sa.types.Integer)
    parent_department_id = sa.Column(sa.types.Integer,
                                     sa.ForeignKey("departments.department_id"))

    parent_department = sa.orm.relation("Department")


engine = sa.create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

/tmp$ python test_s.py

```
2011-03-24 15:09:58,311 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...42cc PRAGMA table_info("departments")
2011-03-24 15:09:58,312 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...42cc ()
2011-03-24 15:09:58,312 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...42cc 
CREATE TABLE departments (
    department_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR(100), 
    chief_id INTEGER, 
    parent_department_id INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (department_id), 
    UNIQUE (name), 
    FOREIGN KEY(parent_department_id) REFERENCES departments (department_id)
)

2011-03-24 15:09:58,312 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...42cc ()
2011-03-24 15:09:58,312 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...42cc COMMIT
```