# Check database schema matches SQLAlchemy models on application startup

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

To prevent human errors, I'd like to check that the current SQL database schema matches the SQLAlchemy models code and there aren't migrations need to run on the application startup. Is there a way to iterate all models on SQLAlchemy and then see if the database schema is that what the model expects it to be?

This is to prevent the errors popping up later (HTTP 500 due to missing table, field, etc.)

Comment: You can get the schema of the models with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128717/sqlalchemy-printing-raw-sql-from-create and compare with the db schema with https://metacpan.org/dist/SQL-Translator/view/script/sqlt-diff

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Based on @yoloseem hints above, here is a complete answer:

```
import logging

from sqlalchemy import inspect
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.clsregistry import _ModuleMarker
from sqlalchemy.orm import RelationshipProperty

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def is_sane_database(Base, session):
    """Check whether the current database matches the models declared in model base.

    Currently we check that all tables exist with all columns. What is not checked

    * Column types are not verified

    * Relationships are not verified at all (TODO)

    :param Base: Declarative Base for SQLAlchemy models to check

    :param session: SQLAlchemy session bound to an engine

    :return: True if all declared models have corresponding tables and columns.
    """

    engine = session.get_bind()
    iengine = inspect(engine)

    errors = False

    tables = iengine.get_table_names()

    # Go through all SQLAlchemy models
    for name, klass in Base._decl_class_registry.items():

        if isinstance(klass, _ModuleMarker):
            # Not a model
            continue

        table = klass.__tablename__
        if table in tables:
            # Check all columns are found
            # Looks like [{'default': "nextval('sanity_check_test_id_seq'::regclass)", 'autoincrement': True, 'nullable': False, 'type': INTEGER(), 'name': 'id'}]

            columns = [c["name"] for c in iengine.get_columns(table)]
            mapper = inspect(klass)

            for column_prop in mapper.attrs:
                if isinstance(column_prop, RelationshipProperty):
                    # TODO: Add sanity checks for relations
                    pass
                else:
                    for column in column_prop.columns:
                        # Assume normal flat column
                        if not column.key in columns:
                            logger.error("Model %s declares column %s which does not exist in database %s", klass, column.key, engine)
                            errors = True
        else:
            logger.error("Model %s declares table %s which does not exist in database %s", klass, table, engine)
            errors = True

    return not errors
```

Below is the py.test testing code to exercise this:

```
"""Tests for checking database sanity checks functions correctly."""

from pyramid_web20.system.model.sanitycheck import is_sane_database
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config, Column, Integer, String
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey


def setup_module(self):
    # Quiet log output for the tests
    import logging
    from pyramid_web20.system.model.sanitycheck import logger
    #logger.setLevel(logging.FATAL)


def gen_test_model():

    Base = declarative_base()

    class SaneTestModel(Base):
        """A sample SQLAlchemy model to demostrate db conflicts. """

        __tablename__ = "sanity_check_test"

        #: Running counter used in foreign key references
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    return Base, SaneTestModel


def gen_relation_models():

    Base = declarative_base()

    class RelationTestModel(Base):
        __tablename__ = "sanity_check_test_2"
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


    class RelationTestModel2(Base):
        __tablename__ = "sanity_check_test_3"
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

        test_relationship_id = Column(ForeignKey("sanity_check_test_2.id"))
        test_relationship = relationship(RelationTestModel, primaryjoin=test_relationship_id == RelationTestModel.id)

    return Base, RelationTestModel, RelationTestModel2


def gen_declarative():

    Base = declarative_base()

    class DeclarativeTestModel(Base):
        __tablename__ = "sanity_check_test_4"
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

        @declared_attr
        def _password(self):
            return Column('password', String(256), nullable=False)

        @hybrid_property
        def password(self):
            return self._password

    return Base, DeclarativeTestModel


def test_sanity_pass(ini_settings, dbsession):
    """See database sanity check completes when tables and columns are created."""

    engine = engine_from_config(ini_settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    conn = engine.connect()
    trans = conn.begin()

    Base, SaneTestModel = gen_test_model()
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    try:
        Base.metadata.drop_all(engine, tables=[SaneTestModel.__table__])
    except sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError:
        pass

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine, tables=[SaneTestModel.__table__])

    try:
        assert is_sane_database(Base, session) is True
    finally:
        Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)


def test_sanity_table_missing(ini_settings, dbsession):
    """See check fails when there is a missing table"""

    engine = engine_from_config(ini_settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    conn = engine.connect()
    trans = conn.begin()

    Base, SaneTestModel = gen_test_model()
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    try:
        Base.metadata.drop_all(engine, tables=[SaneTestModel.__table__])
    except sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError:
        pass

    assert is_sane_database(Base, session) is False


def test_sanity_column_missing(ini_settings, dbsession):
    """See check fails when there is a missing table"""

    engine = engine_from_config(ini_settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    conn = engine.connect()
    trans = conn.begin()

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    Base, SaneTestModel = gen_test_model()
    try:
        Base.metadata.drop_all(engine, tables=[SaneTestModel.__table__])
    except sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError:
        pass
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine, tables=[SaneTestModel.__table__])

    # Delete one of the columns
    engine.execute("ALTER TABLE sanity_check_test DROP COLUMN id")

    assert is_sane_database(Base, session) is False


def test_sanity_pass_relationship(ini_settings, dbsession):
    """See database sanity check understands about relationships and don't deem them as missing column."""

    engine = engine_from_config(ini_settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    conn = engine.connect()
    trans = conn.begin()

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    Base, RelationTestModel, RelationTestModel2  = gen_relation_models()
    try:
        Base.metadata.drop_all(engine, tables=[RelationTestModel.__table__, RelationTestModel2.__table__])
    except sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError:
        pass

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine, tables=[RelationTestModel.__table__, RelationTestModel2.__table__])

    try:
        assert is_sane_database(Base, session) is True
    finally:
        Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)


def test_sanity_pass_declarative(ini_settings, dbsession):
    """See database sanity check understands about relationships and don't deem them as missing column."""

    engine = engine_from_config(ini_settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    conn = engine.connect()
    trans = conn.begin()

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    Base, DeclarativeTestModel = gen_declarative()
    try:
        Base.metadata.drop_all(engine, tables=[DeclarativeTestModel.__table__])
    except sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError:
        pass

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine, tables=[DeclarativeTestModel.__table__])

    try:
        assert is_sane_database(Base, session) is True
    finally:
        Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
```

Comment: nice!  This is an awesome idea for a library.

Comment: It would be perfect if we have it check for column type too besides column name only @MikkoOhtamaa

Answer (score 9):

Check out [Runtime Inspection API](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/inspection.html#module-sqlalchemy.inspection).

You can pass [`Engine`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine) to [`inspect()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/inspection.html?highlight=inspect#sqlalchemy.inspection.inspect) as well. Once you have [`sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html#sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector) object, now you can use [`get_table_names()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html#sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector.get_table_names), [`get_columns(tbl_name)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html#sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector.get_columns), and any other methods(e.g. for primary keys, constraints, indexes, ...) to examine the "real" schema that your database has.

Comment: Thanks! I expanded this a bit - see below.