# Creating schema scripts in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I wish to create scripts containing the sql statements executed by sqlalchemy during table/schema creations. I **DO NOT** want to print a single raw query that I can do using `print(statement.compile(someengine))` but want all the queries to be saved as a script. I know there is a flag called `echo=True` which will log all the queries but it will still be a log and not a script.
After doing some of the googling I landed up on below two links:

1. [SQLAlchemy printing raw SQL from create()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128717/sqlalchemy-printing-raw-sql-from-create/46669075#46669075)
2. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/metadata_schema.html#how-can-i-get-the-create-table-drop-table-output-as-a-string

The documentation link looks promising but throwing me an error 
Example code which I tried:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
uri ='postgresql://user:password@hostname/database_name'
def dump(sql, *multiparams, **params):
    print(sql.compile(dialect=engine.dialect))
engine = create_engine(uri, strategy='mock', executor=dump)
```

Above code is throwing me this error

> 'MockConnection' object has no attribute 'url'

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include the full traceback.

Comment: This is the full stack trace. It is not showing any other error msg except this.

Comment: That is not a traceback, it is the message of an error. If that's all you see, something's catching the exception and just prints the message.

Comment: Also, is this a [mcve]? Does this code reproduce the error in question? It'd seem odd if it does and I suspect there's actually more to it.