# How to use SQLAlchemy models to generate raw SQL which is able to create all tables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

It is possible to generate raw SQL statement to create any SQLAlchemy table [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128717/sqlalchemy-printing-raw-sql-from-create).

However, I would like to generate raw SQL which creates all tables, not just one.

Let's assume I have such tables (this table design is not real-world, but it shows the issue well):

```py
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Text, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/postgres', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "product"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(Text, nullable=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=True)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(Text, nullable=True)
    product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('product.id'), nullable=True)


open("create_tables.sql", 'w').close() # to clear the file

for table in Base.metadata.tables.values():
    table_sql = str(CreateTable(table).compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect()))
    with open("create_tables.sql", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(table_sql)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

(this is complete program, you can run it as-is)

In code above you can see that I use `for` loop to generate raw SQL:

```py
for table in Base.metadata.tables.values():
    table_sql = str(CreateTable(table).compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect()))
    with open("create_tables.sql", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(table_sql)
```

Resulting file contains:

```sql
CREATE TABLE product (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
    name TEXT, 
    user_id INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES "user" (id)
)

CREATE TABLE "user" (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
    name TEXT, 
    product_id INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(product_id) REFERENCES product (id)
)
```

But I can't execute this SQL code, it will give me error due to circular reference. (and I need to add at least some `;`)

---

SQLAlchemy can however create those tables without problem when I use:

```py
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

With `echo=True` the generated SQL is visible in log:

```sql
2021-10-18 05:37:24,442 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select version()
2021-10-18 05:37:24,443 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2021-10-18 05:37:24,447 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select current_schema()
2021-10-18 05:37:24,447 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2021-10-18 05:37:24,449 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine show standard_conforming_strings
2021-10-18 05:37:24,450 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2021-10-18 05:37:24,454 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2021-10-18 05:37:24,455 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select relname from pg_class c join pg_namespace n on n.oid=c.relnamespace where pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid) and relname=%(name)s     
2021-10-18 05:37:24,456 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00073s] {'name': 'product'}  
2021-10-18 05:37:24,459 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select relname from pg_class c join pg_namespace n on n.oid=c.relnamespace where pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid) and relname=%(name)s     
2021-10-18 05:37:24,460 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.004542s ago] {'name': 'user'}2021-10-18 05:37:24,463 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine
CREATE TABLE product (
        id SERIAL NOT NULL,
        name TEXT,
        user_id INTEGER,
        created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


2021-10-18 05:37:24,464 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00116s] {}
2021-10-18 05:37:24,480 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine
CREATE TABLE "user" (
        id SERIAL NOT NULL,
        name TEXT,
        product_id INTEGER,
        created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


2021-10-18 05:37:24,481 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00128s] {}
2021-10-18 05:37:24,494 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ALTER TABLE product ADD FOREIGN KEY(user_id) 
REFERENCES "user" (id)
2021-10-18 05:37:24,495 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00053s] {}
2021-10-18 05:37:24,497 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ALTER TABLE "user" ADD FOREIGN KEY(product_id) REFERENCES product (id)
2021-10-18 05:37:24,497 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00047s] {}
2021-10-18 05:37:24,500 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```

My question is how to get this SQL, which is visible in the log above and is able to create all tables in one transaction, as Python string (or `.sql` file)?

I want to be able to check it / review it and then apply it (or part of it) manually to production server.

Answer (score 0):

You may do this:

1. Generate DDL of the first type into a file;
2. Cut/paste statements like `FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES "user" (id)` to the end of the file;
3. Edit them to become `ALTER TABLE product ADD FOREIGN KEY(user_id)  REFERENCES "user" (id)` (like the second script);

So you first create the tables and then add the foreign key constraints. These are safe & trivial changes that keep the logic intact. Your example becomes:

```sql
CREATE TABLE product (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
    name TEXT, 
    user_id INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id) 
    -- cut FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES "user" (id) and remove a comma
);

CREATE TABLE "user" (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
    name TEXT, 
    product_id INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -- Cut FOREIGN KEY(product_id) REFERENCES product (id) and remove a comma
);

-- Paste and edit here. Prepend "alter table <tablename> add "
alter table product add FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES "user" (id);
alter table "user" add FOREIGN KEY(product_id) REFERENCES product (id);
```

Please note added semicolons after statements. They are missing in the generated DDL.